# Increasing paper height per iteration using printdocument

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, printing, printdocument

i m using printdocument for a printout. i want to increment the size of the paper after each row is added. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064103/print-on-continuous-paper-using-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365360/printing-on-roll-paper). But the solution doesnot work. I m using a Component class to override the base method of Printdocument and I m setting the page size in OnBeginPrint event

```
int pageHt = 288, pageWt = 314;
protected override void OnBeginPrint(System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Run base code
            base.OnBeginPrint(e);
            base.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", pageWt, pageHt);
            base.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;
        }
```

Then for each iteration i m trying to increase the paper height

```
base.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height += 22;
```

But the paper height does not increment. Help appreciated. Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this question after struggling for 2 days. It was pretty simple

```
public void PrintEstimate(PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
  e.PageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", pageWt, pageHt);//initialize the height and width of the page
  foreach(.. )
  {   
    /* ...
     Write the loop here
     ...
     ...
   */
     e.PageSettings.PaperSize.Height = e.PageSettings.PaperSize.Height + 22;// foreach iteration, increment the page height.
   }
}
```